# Tracing multiple TSQL events with different filters per event

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm wanting to trace two events, SP:Completed and SP:StmtCompleted.
I want ALL SP:Completed however I only want SP:StmtCompleted if the ObjectName column is NULL.

What I'm trying to do is track all web site calls for debugging. I want to see all stored procedures, function calls, etc and all direct queries from the website (either hand written or linq, etc). SP:Completed gives me almost everything. When I use SP:StmtCompleted it gives way too much information in that it gives all the calls from within the procedures and functions so I want only NULL ObjectNames If the event is SP:StmtCompleted but want everything for SP:Completed (null and not null objectnames).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this isn't possible directly, since a trace filter condition can [reference only one column, not two, and only one comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174404.aspx). So you can't construct a 'complex' filter condition like `(Event = A and ObjectName is NULL) OR (Event = B)`.

A couple of alternatives would be:

- Save the trace output to a table and query the table, using either [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190633%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or [`fn_trace_gettable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188425.aspx)
- Use extended events (which are supposed to replace traces, although I've never used them)